# Scrape YouTube video views

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube, screen-scraping

I have a list of youtube video links like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywZevdHW5bQ and I need to scrape the views count using BeautifulSoup and requests library

Comment: Okaaay... and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywZevdHW5bQ'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('meta[itemprop="interactionCount"][content]')['content'])
```

Prints:

```
5186856
```

Comment: I am getting results for views and other fields as well, but views count seem to differ a lot for certain videos. Actual views and the ones that are printed.

Comment: @ManosPratikakis Your best bet is to use official Google API for getting that value. It's hard to scrape it from the pages like now.

Comment: Would you mind giving [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893932/cant-fetch-some-content-from-a-webpage-using-post-requests) a look in case there is any solution to offer @Andrej Kesely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is getting yourself a Youtube API key, then using `videos/list` api endpoint to get information about the video, then using the response to extract `viewCount`.

1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python
2. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
3. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource