# Can't fetch some content from a webpage using post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python in association with selenium to scrape some content located within a box like container in it's left sidebar from a webpage. When I use selenium I can get them without any trouble. Now, i would like to get the same content using requests module. I did some experiments in dev tools and noticed that there is a post requests being sent which produces some json response that I've pasted below. However, at this point I'm stuck as to how I can fetch the content using requests.

[webpage link](http://wave.webaim.org/report#/www.onewerx.com)

Selenium approch:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def get_content(link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tab-outline"))).click()
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pageoutline > [class^='outline_H']"))):
        print(item.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "http://wave.webaim.org/report#/www.onewerx.com"
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        get_content(url)
```

Partial output the script produces (as desired):

```
Marketing Mix Modeling
Programmatic & Modeling
Programmatic is buying digital advertising space automatically, with computers using data to decide which ads to buy and how much to pay for them.
Modern
Efficient
Scalable
Resultative
What is Modeling?
Modeling is an analytical approach that uses historic information, such as syndicated point-of-sale data and companies’ internal data, to quantify the sales impact of various marketing activities.
Programmatic - future of the marketing
```

When trying with requests:

```
import requests

url = "http://wave.webaim.org/data/request.php"

headers = {
    'Referer': 'http://wave.webaim.org/report',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

res = requests.post(url,data={'source':'http://www.onewerx.com'},headers=headers)
print(res.json())
```

I get the following output:

```
{'success': True, 'reportkey': '6520439253ac21885007b52c677b8078', 'contenttype': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

***How can I get the same content using requests?***

To be clearer:
[This is what I'm interested in](https://filebin.net/iydqujehfmzib8vy).

The output above looks different from the image because the selenium script click on the following button attached to that box to expand the content:

[image]

Comment: If you look at res.json, it's providing you with metadata about the response such as headers and status code and the contenttype which in your case is `text/html`. Try res.text or res.content.

Comment: They both `res.text` and `res.content` produce the same thing @Himanshu Pant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done a bit of reverse engineering.
It seems like the whole process runs on the client side. Here's how:

`wave.engine.statistics` contains the result you're looking for:

```
// wave.min.js

wave.fn.applyRules = function() {
    var e = {};
    e.statistics = {};
    try {
        e.categories = wave.engine.run(),
        e.statistics = wave.engine.statistics;
        wave.engine.ruleTimes;
        e.statistics.pagetitle = wave.page.title,
        e.statistics.totalelements = wave.allTags.length,
        e.success = !0
    } catch (t) {
        console.log(t)
    }
    return e
}
```

Here `wave.engine.run` function runs all rules on the client side. `s` is the `<body>` element:

[image: rules]

and returns the results

```
wave.engine.run = function(e) {
    var t = new Date
      , n = null
      , i = null
      , a = new Date;
    wave.engine.fn.calculateContrast(this.fn.getBody());
    var o = new Date
      , r = wave.rules
      , s = $(wave.page);
    if (e)
        r[e] && r[e](s);
    else
        for (e in r) {
            n = new Date;
            try {
                r[e](s)
            } catch (l) {
                console.log("RULE FAILURE(" + e + "): " + l.stack)
            }
            i = new Date,
            this.ruleTimes[e] = i - n,
            config.debug && console.log("RULE: " + e + " (" + this.ruleTimes[e] + "ms)")
        }
    return EndTimer = new Date,
    config.debug && console.log("TOTAL RULE TIME: " + (EndTimer - t) + "ms"),
    a = new Date,
    wave.engine.fn.structureOutput(),
    o = new Date,
    wave.engine.results
}
```

So you have two options: port these rules into Python, or keep using Selenium.

```
wave.rules = {},
wave.rules.text_justified = function(e) {
    e.find("p, div, td").each(function(t, n) {
        var i = e.find(n);
        "justify" == i.css("text-align") && wave.engine.fn.addIcon(n, "text_justified")
    })
}
,
wave.rules.alt_missing = function(e) {
    wave.engine.fn.overrideby("alt_missing", ["alt_link_missing", "alt_map_missing", "alt_spacer_missing"]),
    e.find("img:not([alt])").each(function(e, t) {
        var n = $(t);
        void 0 != n.attr("title") && 0 != n.attr("title").length || wave.engine.fn.addIcon(t, "alt_missing")
    })
}
// ... and many more
```

Since the tests rely on the browser engine to render a page fully (reports are not generated on the cloud unfortunately), you have to use Selenium for this job